# Volley String Response of XML data and parse xml data

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

Following is my approach:

```
private void liveScores(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        if(requestQueue == null)
        {
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LiveScores.this);

        }
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

What I want is that i'm getting this response in string and this is xml data. I'm not able to use xmlpullparse in this. Can any one tell me how to make it async means these are live scores data and how to keep it refreshing after a while and also how to get objects of this response differentiate. 
[this is link of xml response](http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml) and i want to get title element and put it in Listview. 
Any help will be appreciated thanks.